# LoF/LoT Number Postfix

Tags: table-of-contents

What did I do???

All I did is add a nested table like so
[image: Nested table added]

Now, my LoT and LoF are all rendering with "table" or "figure" immediately after the number, behind the actual title/caption like so.

[image: The broken text]

I'm using the report class with the following packages

- titlesec
- listings
- setspace
- changepage
- indentfirst

I've been digging for a few hours and can't seem to find anything to point me in the right direction.  Do you have any ideas on how to remove the text?

I was able to produce the following MWE from lyx

```
\documentclass[english]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{showcaptionsetup}{}{%
 \PassOptionsToPackage{caption=false}{subfig}}
\usepackage{subfig}
\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\listoftables

\begin{table}
\subfloat[Child Table]{
}
\caption{A Table}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Sigh - This issue appears to be environment specific.  I tried running it on my Linux machine and the issue does not present there.  For the time being, I'll just work on it there.  I'll post back later if I find a solution when I have time.

Thanks anyway

Comment: Dunno. Pls provide a minimum working example. Merry Xmas.

Comment: That's just it, I don't have any clue how to reproduce it beyond adding a nested figure or table.  The only content I have relative to LoF/LoT is to replace the headers ```\renewcommand{\listoffigures}{%
\pagebreak\begin{center}\mdseries\MakeUppercase{\listfigurename}\end{center}\par%
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\hspace*{-1em}\MakeUppercase{\listfigurename}}%
\hfill\null\\Figure\hfill{Page}\par%
\@starttoc{lof}%
}```

Comment: I don't get any overprinting in the list of tables from the example in your question.

Comment: If you think it is environment specific use `\listfiles` and compile on both machines. Then compare the list of files and versions produced in each case.

Comment: I suspect the recent `caption` package bug. Is `caption` package loaded/up to date?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thank you for the tip.  I removed the caption package and re-installed it, and the issue is remedied!  Now i just have to hunt my way through to make sure nothing else is off.. Thanks

Comment: @RyanL: Alright. If you have other issues, please post a new question then. Can we close this question?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved by a software update.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @ChristianHupfer in the comments, this was resolved by reinstalling the caption package.

Comment: Normally, I would consider it more polite to ask the person that answered your question in the comments to convert their comment to an answer and then accept that. If they don't reply or let it go, you are of course free to add an answer yourself. If the solution is a re-installation or update often questions are closed as "off topic" (they aren't really, but that is the best reason there is). The questions are often very localised and relevant for a short period of time. Christian even suggested it himself. So I will go for that solution.

Comment: @moewe: It's alright. I could not have posted more than the O.P. had done.